# The input keeps repeating itself

Tags: python, math

Hello I'm new in programming, I was coding newton's method for a uni class, and the part where the user input the f(x) in the code keeps repeating.

This is the code I was making, it works but the def f(x) keeps repeating for 2 or 3 times before the while starts

```
import math
import sympy as smp
from sympy import *
x = smp.symbols('x')
x0=float(input("Initial Value:"))
k=1
n=int(input("Number of interactions:"))
def f(x):
  return eval(input("f(x):"))
f_prime= smp.diff(f(x), x)
f_prime = lambdify(x, f_prime)
while(k<=n):
  r=x0-(f(x0)/f_prime(x0))
  print("root:",r,"interaction:",k)
  k=k+1
  x0=r
```

Comment: Don't use `eval`. Ever. (Maybe you'll discover a real need for it some day, but don't look for reasons to use  it.)

Comment: What should I use then?

Comment: You need to read about sympy.  It wants to see your function as a STRING, not as an evaluated result.  And you need to store it as a string that you reuse, not in a function that asks for new input each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the code as follows.

**Code**

```
from sympy import Symbol, diff, sympify

def newton_method(func, sym, x0, n = 10):
    diff_func = diff(func, x)    # derivative of function
    
    root = x0
    for i in range(n):
        root = root - float(func.subs(x, root)/diff_func.subs(x, root))
        
    return root
   
# Setup
expression = input('input function: ')      # String expression corresponding to function
f = sympify(expression)                     # string expression to sympy function
x0 = float(input("Initial Value:"))        
n = int(input("Number of interactions:"))  

# Find root
root = newton_method(f, Symbol('x'), x0, n) # newton method with x as symbol

print('root:', root)
```

**Test**

```
input function:  x**2 - 2*x + 1
Initial Value: 0
Number of interactions: 10
root: 0.9990234375
```